# Constrain left join

Tags: mysql, left-join, greatest-n-per-group

I am using a left join to solve a greatest-n-per-group problem. It works well for getting the most recent values by date in datum column.

```
SELECT t1.* FROM druckerdaten.druckerdaten AS t1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN druckerdaten.druckerdaten AS t2 
ON t1.ip = t2.ip AND (t1.datum < t2.datum OR (t1.datum = t2.datum AND t1.nr < t2.nr)) 
WHERE t2.ip IS NULL ORDER BY t1.ip;
```

Next I want to get the most recent values before a specific date in datum column, but I have no idea how to achieve this.
Neither eg. datum<'2017-05-22 10:00:00' in WHERE clause nor in ON clause works.

Here is a example dataset:

```
----------------------------------------------------
|nr   |datum               |ip          |value     |
----------------------------------------------------
|1    |2017-05-01 15:00:00 |192.168.0.1 |a         |
|2    |2017-05-01 16:00:00 |192.168.0.2 |b         |
|3    |2017-05-01 17:00:00 |192.168.0.1 |c         |
|4    |2017-05-02 15:00:00 |192.168.0.2 |d         |
|5    |2017-05-02 16:00:00 |192.168.0.2 |e         |
----------------------------------------------------
```

Result of above query is:

```
----------------------------------------------------
|nr   |datum               |ip          |value     |
----------------------------------------------------
|3    |2017-05-01 17:00:00 |192.168.0.1 |c         |
|5    |2017-05-02 16:00:00 |192.168.0.2 |e         |
----------------------------------------------------
```

Now datum column is constrained in where-clause using following query:

```
SELECT t1.* FROM druckerdaten.druckerdaten AS t1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN druckerdaten.druckerdaten AS t2 
ON t1.ip = t2.ip AND (t1.datum < t2.datum OR (t1.datum = t2.datum AND t1.nr < t2.nr)) 
WHERE t2.ip IS NULL AND datum<'2017-05-02 00:00:00' ORDER BY t1.ip;
```

This gives me this result:

```
----------------------------------------------------
|nr   |datum               |ip          |value     |
----------------------------------------------------
|3    |2017-05-01 17:00:00 |192.168.0.1 |c         |
----------------------------------------------------
```

But it should give:

```
----------------------------------------------------
|nr   |datum               |ip          |value     |
----------------------------------------------------
|2    |2017-05-01 16:00:00 |192.168.0.2 |b         |
|3    |2017-05-01 17:00:00 |192.168.0.1 |c         |
----------------------------------------------------
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Seems to me that putting this condition in the where should work.
can you provide an example dataset and desired result, and how putting the condition fails?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I added some example data in my question

Comment: I am having a similar issue. I am trying to constrain a left join to show only the records with a specific date but it doesnt return results.Did you find anything?

Answer (score 0):

Is it like so?

```
SELECT t1.* FROM druckerdaten AS t1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN druckerdaten AS t2 
ON t1.ip != t2.ip 
WHERE t1.datum < '2017-05-02 00:00:00' AND t2.datum < '2017-05-02 00:00:00' 
AND t1.nr >= t2.nr
group by t2.ip
ORDER BY t1.nr ASC;
```

[SQL FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ca0833/75)

Comment: @FelR have you checked?

Comment: Yes, have tried it, but it didn't work. Currently I'm using a workaround:  SELECT t1.* FROM (SELECT * FROM druckerdaten WHERE datum < '2017-05-02 00:00:00) AS t1. But it doesn't perform very performant